Old British movie with a son in a secret room
I'm looking for a British movie (Thames the company), a thriller I think, from 1980 or before.
The plot was about a child that is playing outside and by accidently he kills somebody (I don't remember), and his mother built a small room (I think under the stairs) and hides him while police is looking for him.
One day the mother leaves from the house for stuff, and if I remember right she has an accident and dies, so the child stays alone now at his secret room.
Due of the mother's death, a new family moves in this house, and the child at night gets out of his secret room and eats the food.
That's all I remember. Can you help me please to find this movie/the title?

Sounds like Bad Ronald from 1974.

A shy teenager accidentally kills a mocking peer's equally mocking younger sibling, and his mother helps him hide in a spare room in their house. Problems arise when the mother goes for an operation and dies, and the house is sold to a new family, with the teen still living inside.

It was American, though, not British. It was based on a book by the same name. Here's the trailer:



